# Android app OutOfMemoryError while decoding bitmap stream

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am facing this problem: OutOfMemoryError!!

Here is the screen that causes the problem:

[image]

When I using mouse to scroll down. My app suddenly shutdown, and here is what logcat shows:

```
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:530)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:603)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at com.ptit.piclient.tools.AllSongAdapter2$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(AllSongAdapter2.java:91)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at com.ptit.piclient.tools.AllSongAdapter2$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(AllSongAdapter2.java:1)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-05 08:25:36.469: E/AndroidRuntime(8941):     ... 4 more
```

It says that problem is the `DownloadImageTask` class. And here is the code of that class:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        ImageView imgView;
        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView img){this.imgView = img;}

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urlDisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap icon = null;
            InputStream in = null ;
            try {
                in = new URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //khuongdv start sep28
            finally{
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //khuongdv end sep28
            return icon;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
            if(result == null) return;
            imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Can you point out why is this and how to fix this!?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to handle the bitmap size, it is causing the out of memory error. Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966 Please also consider lazy loading of listview when doing so from a webservice.

Comment: Can you tell me more details?

Comment: You are trying to load the full scale images. Since there are a list of them it may cause out of memory. follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/827110

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: icon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon,64,64,false); after icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); try that

Comment: @Songokute-Just add external storage permission in manifest.xml file sometimes this is the reason to showing that type of error

Comment: @FarhaSameer786: I did add two permissions about storage (WRITE and READ EXTERNAL STORAGE) :(
@ JRowan: Thanks , it works. No error occurs now :D 
@ Amulya Khare and @ Pirate Cube and yanchenko: Thank you all ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Use the imageloader from the lazylist which is in following link it will help you to load image from url and meanwhile you can show temp image. and it also provide file caching  so  next time you don't need to download that image again.

[LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

use the following code wherever you want to load image.

`ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this);`
`imageLoader.displayImage(url,imageview);`

and add user permission to write external storage b'coze of it's use file caching.

Hope you findout it useful...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a lazy list goes far enough to resolve this problem.  It is if you're loading from disk but otherwise it's not because a single image might be sufficient to take all your memory.

BitmapFactory has methods  to decode only the header so that you do a second pass decode that will downscale the image to avoid this problem.  However, it's much simpler to use something like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and let it handle this for you.